# How to union SELECT two tables with ids of both tables?

Tags: sql, mysql, union, union-all

Ok, I have four tables:

Table 1: "f_withholdings"

[image]

Table 2: "f_wh_list"

[image]

Table 3: "f_rpayments"

[image]

Table 4: "f_rp_list"

[image]

Table 1 and Table 2 are connected with each other by `wh_id` field
and Table 3 and Table 4 are connected by `rp_id` as seen in picture.

I want to union select both tables into one, something like:

```
SELECT
`wh_list_id`,
`wh_name` AS `name`,
`wh_list_date` AS `date`,
`wh_list_amount` AS `amount`,
`wh_list_pending` AS `pending`,
`wh_list_comment` AS `comment`
FROM
`f_wh_list` LEFT JOIN `f_withholdings` ON `f_wh_list`.`wh_id` = `f_withholdings`.`wh_id`

UNION ALL

SELECT
`rp_list_id`,
`rp_name` AS `name`,
`rp_list_date` AS `date`,
`rp_list_amount` AS `amount`,
`rp_list_pending` AS `pending`,
`rp_list_comment` AS `comment`
FROM `f_rp_list` LEFT JOIN `f_rpayments` ON `f_rp_list`.`rp_id` = `f_rpayments`.`rp_id`
```

and I get this:

[image]

there is only one id field from first SELECT `wh_list_id` in result table, but no `rp_list_id`

I'd like to have both ids in result table, something like below:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just select `null` as the column that is missing from each.

```
SELECT
`wh_list_id`,
null AS `rp_list_id`,
`wh_name` AS `name`,
`wh_list_date` AS `date`,
`wh_list_amount` AS `amount`,
`wh_list_pending` AS `pending`,
`wh_list_comment` AS `comment`
FROM
`f_wh_list` LEFT JOIN `f_withholdings` ON `f_wh_list`.`wh_id` = `f_withholdings`.`wh_id`

UNION ALL

SELECT
null as `wh_list_id`,
`rp_list_id`,
`rp_name` AS `name`,
`rp_list_date` AS `date`,
`rp_list_amount` AS `amount`,
`rp_list_pending` AS `pending`,
`rp_list_comment` AS `comment`
FROM `f_rp_list` LEFT JOIN `f_rpayments` ON `f_rp_list`.`rp_id` = `f_rpayments`.`rp_id`
```

Comment: +1: Same comment as to Dmitri about about column aliases - most databases don't need the explicit alias in statements defined after the first statement of a UNION.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a corresponding null column to each query (UNIONs work off of column position, they don't care about names or aliases):

```
SELECT
`wh_list_id`,
NULL,
...

SELECT
NULL,
`rp_list_id`,
...
```

It may be slightly better to keep the ids in one column, and add a field that specifies which query the id is from (`SELECT 'wh_list', ...` for example).

Comment: +1: If you want to reference a column, aliases matter ;) The column reference is defined by the first of the UNION'd statements.

Comment: Only if you want to reference it by name :) (which, fair enough, you should)